# Apache Reverse Proxy based on URL

Tags: apache2

I have Metabase application server set up on port 3000 and need to use Apache 2 (on RHEL7) as a reverse proxy.

Below config works will for root url '/'

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com.my
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But my intention is to have this work for '/metabase'. Below configuration doesn't work. Basic HTML seems to load i.e. ,  etc, but I suspect all the JS and CSS static files do not work, because the page is blank.

```
# NOT WORKING
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com.my
  ProxyPass /metabase http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse /metabase http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing in the config?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not missing anything in the config, as you say, the Basic HTML seems to load.

The HTML probably expects to be at the root directory and not in some sub directory. Look at the links that are generated for Images, CSS and JS.

Comment: This is most likely true. The best way is to open the console in the webbroswer and it will most likely show alot of 404