# Apache 2 proxy external images from any domain

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy

I am working on a project that would require my server to proxy images from any domain.

The idea would be that https://icontrolthisdomain.net/https://somerandomdomain.org/some-random-route/image.png would actually proxy the image to the user. If it caches it, it would be a plus too, but the only important thing right now is to proxy it.

There is a question like this one but they always proxy the same domain. In my case it would be any domain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476486/apache-proxy-proxy-based-on-url

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked @GeraldSchneider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Reverse Proxy based on URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/931126/apache-reverse-proxy-based-on-url)